# Unknown column in where clause in query without where clause

Tags: mysql, where-clause, mysql-error-1054

I have following table:

```
CREATE TABLE `pckgs` (
`idPckg` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`name` char(32) COLLATE utf8_polish_ci NOT NULL,
`customCount` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`baseCustomCount` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
PRIMARY KEY (`idPckg`),
UNIQUE KEY `name` (`name`),
KEY `customCount` (`customCount`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_polish_ci
```

I have only one record in the table. I try to execute statement:

`DELETE FROM pckgs;`

but I got the error:

```
ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'packOnly' in 'where clause'
```

It's kind of weird because I dont have any where clause in my simple query plus there is no such column as packOnly in a whole database. I need to delete it, how? I cannot restart server.

Comment: you are not showing the whole query. I can't see any statement that uses `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Probably you are running another query

Comment: @bonCodigo Your comment should be *Where's the `Where`?*

Comment: Have you any trigger on the table?

Comment: That's exactly the problem. I enter the query 'DELETE FROM pcksg'. End. No WHERE clause. Other way reason would be obvious.

Comment: No triggers. There are also no rows in other tables that are connected by foreign keys to the pckgs table.

Comment: The possibility is that there are triggers set on the table or there are executing the wrong query. Bare in mind that the server is not lying.

Comment: Thank you JW! Trigger was the problem. Completely forgot about it. Probably that's why I strongly avoid using triggers. Thanks. Add answer and I'll accept it so it can be solved.

Comment: +1 MahmoudGamal :D @Joe *Some legendary left over is hunting you down*...perhaps do a `show triggers`

Comment: @bonCodigo - well, at least that was kind of funny thread :]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The possibility is that **there are triggers set on the table** or you are executing the wrong query. Bare in mind that the server is not lying. `:D`

**Triggers** are *evil*!

Comment: That was actually only one trigger in the DB. Hah. Hasta la vista - trigger! :]